# Doctrine ManyToMany Relation 'The table with name already exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I have Entity **Party**.  Shortly it looks like this:

```
     AppBundle\Entity\Main\Party:
        type: entity
        table: main.party
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                nullable: false
                id: true
                generator:
                    strategy: IDENTITY
        fields:
            legalName:
                type: string
                nullable: false
                length: 255
                options:
                    fixed: false
                column: legal_name
    manyToMany:
        partiesForPartner:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Main\Party
            mappedBy: partnersForParty
            fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
            cache:
                usage: NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE
        partnersForParty:
            cascade: ["all"]
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Main\Party
            inversedBy: partiesForPartner
            fetch: LAZY
            joinTable:
                name: main.party_partnership
                joinColumns:
                    party_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    partner_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
```

Also there is one more entity **PartyPartnership**. which includes some additional props.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Main\PartyPartnership:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\Main\PartyPartnershipRepository
    table: main.party_partnership
    uniqueConstraints:
        party_partnership_ukey:
            columns:
                - party_id
                - partner_id
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        codePartyByPartner:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 35
            options:
                fixed: false
            column: code_party_by_partner
        codePartnerByParty:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 35
            options:
                fixed: false
            column: code_partner_by_party
    manyToOne:
        party:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Main\Party
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                party_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        partner:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Main\Party
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                partner_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

All this mapping was imported from DB except of many-to-many association in **Party**. Now when i try to start doctrine commands like 'doctrine:schema:validate' or 'doctrine:schema:update'. I get an error 'The table with name 'main.party_partnership' already exists.'

Answer (score 2):

Symfony ManyToMany creates a table between the two entities linked.
It means it automatically create the table `main.party_partnership` between `party` and `partnership`.

```
Party        ---(ManyToMany main.party_partnership)---> Partnership
```

You just need to reference as `oneToMany`, and remove the `manyToMany`

```
Party        ---(OneToMany)---> PartyPartnership
Partnership  ---(OneToMany)---> PartyPartnership
```

Comment: This is indeed so. The table "main.party_partnership" contains the relations between "party" with additional properties. I'm sure that the error in the wrong definition of the connection is many-to-many. but I can not figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after several hours: clear cache.